# Why did Magnus Carlsen drop out of World Championship in 2011?

Tags: history, world-championship, carlsen, famous-players

I heard from a friend of mine that Magnus Carlsen did not play the Candidate Matches in 2011. Why did he do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Magnus Carlsen drops out of World Championship cycle](http://en.chessbase.com/post/magnus-carlsen-drops-out-of-world-championship-cycle) (contemporaneous chessbase.com article)

Largely he didn't like the format (knockout matches rather than round-robin tournament).

Carlsen wrote a letter to FIDE explaining why he skipped the Candidates Matches, quoted in part below:

> After careful consideration I’ve reached the conclusion that the
>   ongoing 2008–2012 cycle does not represent a system, sufficiently
>   modern and fair, to provide the motivation I need to go through a
>   lengthy process of preparations and matches and to perform at my best.
>
> Reigning champion privileges, the long (five year) span of the cycle,
>   changes made during the cycle resulting in a new format (Candidates)
>   that no World Champion has had to go through since Kasparov, puzzling
>   ranking criteria as well as the shallow ceaseless match-after-match
>   concept are all less than satisfactory in my opinion.
>
> In my opinion privileges should in general be abolished and a future
>   World Championship model should be based on a fair fight between the
>   best players in the World, on equal terms. This should apply also to
>   the winner of the previous World Championship, and especially so when
>   there are several players at approximately the same level in the world
>   elite.
>
> One possibility for future cycles would be to stage an 8-10 player
>   World Championship tournament similar to the 2005 and 2007 events.